# Is it possible to access SAS datasets from a SQL client?

Tags: sas

We have datasets that are created and stored in SAS. I'm curious if it is possible to access those datasets from a remote SQL client. Why? To make those datasets more broadly accessible within our organization.

Comment: What do you mean by "from a remote SQL client"?

Comment: I mean from a SQL client such as SQuirreLSQL

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can license a product called SAS/SHARE that includes something called SHARE*NET.  This is a very useful product that typically is installed in a BI server environment but I suppose it's possible to run on a local desktop.

Basically, you "register" SAS libraries to a service which then makes the data available to external clients over ODBC.  This makes the data sets available as "tables" for applications like Excel, so I'm sure you can use other clients as well.

The SAS ODBC driver itself does not require a license, but the SAS/SHARE software does.  I use it to make data available to many users who do not have direct access to my UNIX server.

Comment: Doco for the odbc driver product, in case anyone is looking, is here: http://support.sas.com/software/products/odbc/

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible through SAS/ACCESS (or something similar), but SAS datasets typically cannot be understood by third-party software.